# Viewing all messages in sub folders in the containing folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have rules set up in Outlook 2010 to move a copy of an email from a particular person to a particular subfolder of a folder

i.e. I have folder Team with subfolders, Joe, Mark, Nige  and  Becky. A rule is applied to incoming email that *moves a copy* of messages from these 4 to their specific folder.

Now what I want is to be able to see all these messages together in the Staff folder (like a specific inbox) too. Is this possible?

Comment: You could just have a seperate rule create another copy in the main folder "Team".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use your rule to move (or copy) the messages to lots of other folders then use a Search folder to bring them back together again, but this leads to the more radical proposal...

Stop using your rules for this, and especially stop making more than one copy of an email. Instead, leave these in the Inbox or use a single rule to move them all to a single folder called "Staff" (maybe as a subfolder of your Inbox).

Then use search folders as "virtual folders" to find mails from Joe, Mark, etc. Of course, you could use a search folder for the "Staff" one as well, rather than having any rules running at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a **Search Folder** for "Mail from specific people" and add your team members to it.

It will also contain messages from your team members that are NOT in your Team folder but that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I too thought of using a Search folder for this, but then realised this was solving the wrong problem, hence my separate answer